# MvcConrib Grid's Sortable property don't seems to to do any effect

Tags: grid, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I need a way to generate the header texts in the grid as sortalbe link.

Do I need to use custom renderer to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GridSortOptions and call the .Sort(YourModel.GridSortOptions) method on the grid and then handle the OrderBy in your controller action.

See this link: http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/03/14/mvccontrib-grid-part-6-sorting/

Thanks,

Hal